# Choose which CSV to import when running a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, csv

I get a CSV every week that our finance team puts in a shared drive. I have a script for that CSV that I run once I get it.

The first command of the script is of course `Import-Csv`.

The problem is, the finance team insists on naming the file differently each time plus they don't always put it in the same location within the drive.

As a result, I have to first hunt for the file, put it into the directory that the script points to and then rename the file.

I've tried talking to the team about putting it in the same location and making sure the filename is the same but they only follow the instructions for a couple of weeks before just doing whatever.

Ideally, I'd like for it so that when I run the script, there would be a popup that would ask me to pick a CSV (Similar to how it looks when you do "Save As" on an Office Document).

Anyway for this to be done within PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

You can access .Net classes and interface with the forms library to instantiate and take input from the standard FileOpen dialog. Something like below:

```
Using Namespace System.Windows.Forms

$FileBrowser = [OpenFileDialog]::new()
$FileBrowser.InitialDirectory = 'c:\temp'
$FileBrowser.Filter = 'Comma Separated Values (*.csv) | *.csv'
[Void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

$CsvFile = $FileBrowser.FileName
```

Then use `$CsvFile` int he `Import-Csv` command.

You can change the `.InitialDirectory` property to make navigating a little more convenient.

Use the `.Filter` property to limit the file open display to CSV files, to make things that much more convenient.

Also, use the `[Void]` class to prevent the status return (usually 'OK' or 'Cancel') from echoing to the screen.

Note: A simple Google search will turn up many examples. I refined some of the work from [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-create-an-open-file-folder-dialog-box-with-powershell/).  That will also document some of the other properties if you want to explore etc.

Comment: Hi Steve, Just to let you know this worked great. Ended up having to add Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms to the 2nd line but after that, all perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked out.  I tested the code shortly before posting it and didn't need `Add-Type`, however there's no harm and that is what the cmdlet is purposed for.  The `Using` documentation also suggests that the `Add-Type` functionality is satisfied by `Using`.  But, my primary interest in the `Using` statement/Directive is the ability to shorten type references. There may be advantaged to using `Add-Type`, like better error handling possibilities.  I consider that to be true when weighing the use of `Using` versus `Import-Module`. The cmdlet offers a little more flexibility etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to settle for a selection box that doesn't look as nice as the Save As dialog,  you can use `Out-Gridview`.  Something along these lines might help.

```
$filenames =
     @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Recurse -Filter  *.csv  |
         Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
         Out-GridView -Title 'Choose a file' -PassThru)

$csvfile = $filenames[0].FullName

Import-Csv $csvfile | More
```

The `-Path` specifies a directory that contains all the locations where your csv file might be delivered.  The sort is just to put the recently written files at the top of the grid.  This supposedly makes selection easier.  The `@()` wrapper merely makes sure the result stored in `$filenames` is an array.

You would do something else with the results of `Import-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Steven's response certainly satisfies your original question, but an alternative would be to let PowerShell do the work. If you know the drive, and you know the name of the file this week, you can pass the name to your script and let it search the drive filtering on the specific csv file you need. Make it recursive, and open the only file that matches. Sorry, didn't have time yesterday to include code. Here's a function that returns the full file path when provided with a top level search path and a filename with possible wildcards.

**function gfp { $result=gci $args[0] -recurse -include $args[1]; return ($result.DirectoryName + "\" + $result.Name) }**

Example: ***gfp "d:\rootfolder" "thisweeksfilename.csv"***